# MediaWiki login through php api

Tags: php, api, mediawiki

Is possible to write a hook for MediaWiki using php to login with a particular user name and password when a certain event takes place? I looked through the MediaWiki api and it seems that $wgUser has only a logout function and does not have a login function.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible to log in to a wiki using a particular user name and password--that is essentially what every authentication extension does. There is a whole page of the [Mediawiki API dedicated to login functionality](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login), and there is also documentation of the [AuthPlugin class](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classAuthPlugin.html), which provides an interface for Mediawiki authentication and login plugins.

If you're looking for code samples for logging into a wiki, there are php examples on the [API:Login](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login) page, and you could also have a look at the extensions in the [authentication and login category](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Authentication_and_login) on Mediawiki.org.

Re: `$wgUser`: login is handled by `$wgUser`'s new methods -- `newFromId`, `newFromName`, `newFromConfirmationCode`, etc. These functions create a new `User` object, which contains data and functionality specific to the account, every time someone logs into their account on the wiki. There is a different set of functions for creating new accounts.